# mouse events on line segments on google maps polyline

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map displaying a polyline.  I can detect mouseover events for the whole line, but I want to catch these events on the line-segment level.  Is there a way to do this while still using just one polyline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not possible since the google maps polyline object is really just one.